# Right way to use gapi.client.drive in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to use drive to save data from chrome extension.

First, I set needed options to manifest.json

```
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "999999.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata"
    ]
},
```

Then try to get list of files:

```
$.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/client.js", function () {

    gapi.load('client', function () {

        console.log("gapi.client is loaded")

        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', function () {

            console.log("gapi.client.drive is loaded");

            chrome.identity.getAuthToken({'interactive': true}, function (token) {

                gapi.client.setToken({access_token: token});

                console.log("token :", token);

                gapi.client.drive.files.list().then(function (list) {
                    console.log(list)
                })

            });

        });
    });
});
```

Console said:

```
gapi.client is loaded
gapi.client.drive is loaded
token : [TOKEN]
```

And the error is like that:

```
"code": 403,
"message": "The granted scopes do not give access to all of the requested spaces."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that you are trying to access unauthorized spaces. Your scope only allows you to use the "appDataFolder" space. Therefore, you have to change

`gapi.client.drive.files.list()`

for

`gapi.client.drive.files.list({spaces:"appDataFolder"})`.